# Apply a trained Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

During the training process, I split the dataset into training and testing data with train_test_split():

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=28)

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print ('History length: ',history)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("logs", sess.graph)

    plt.ion()
    plt.show()

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        shuffle_ind=np.random.permutation(X_train.shape[0])
        y_train=y_train.iloc[shuffle_ind,:]
        X_train=X_train[shuffle_ind,:]

        for batch_no in range(X_train.shape[0]//batch_size):
            seq_len=[history]*batch_size

            batch_X=X_train[batch_no*batch_size:(batch_no+1)*batch_size,:]
            batch_y=y_train.iloc[batch_no*batch_size:(batch_no+1)*batch_size,:]

            feed = {data_pl: batch_X, target_pl: batch_y.iloc[:,1:], seq_len_pl:seq_len,keep_prob_pl:0.5} #1.0
            _,batch_loss = sess.run([train_op,tf_loss], feed_dict=feed)

        feed = {data_pl: X_test, target_pl: y_test.iloc[:,1:], seq_len_pl:[history]*X_test.shape[0],keep_prob_pl:0.5}
        test_loss,predictions,acc_np = sess.run([tf_loss,preds,tf_acc], feed_dict=feed)

        p_=np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
        l_=np.argmax(np.array(y_test.iloc[:,1:]),axis=1)
        acc = sum(p_==l_)/float(len(p_))

        print ("train_acc: ", acc, "test_acc: ", acc_np)

        feed = {data_pl: X_train, target_pl: y_train.iloc[:,1:], seq_len_pl:[history]*X_train.shape[0],keep_prob_pl:0.5}
        train_loss = sess.run(tf_loss, feed_dict=feed)

        print ("Train loss: ",train_loss," Test loss: ",test_loss)
```

After training and getting the accuracy rates, how to apply this trained model on the entire dataset rather than only the testing data?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the ‘OutPut’ is an export of the neural network; thus, the ‘InPut’ is where you can feed your data in. Then, you run the network with the same session that you were training in. The ‘OutPutData’ will be the computing result.

```
OutPutData = session.run(OutPut, feed_dict={ InPut: Data})
```

Answer (score 0):

The Tensorflow needs an empty network structure before the saved variables are restored. If you do not like this, I recommend the Keras. In this example, the famous AlexNet is restored to classify some images. I hope it contains the code that you need.

```
import time
import tensorflow as tf
from alexnet import AlexNet
from imageio import imread
import numpy as np
from caffe_classes import class_names

#Tensor 
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 227, 227, 3))
probs = AlexNet(x, feature_extract=False)


sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_file = './model.ckpt'
saver.restore(sess, save_file)

# Read Images
im1 = (imread(".\Example_Figs\weasel.png")[:, :, :3]).astype(np.float32)
im1 = im1 - np.mean(im1)
im1[:, :, 0], im1[:, :, 2] = im1[:, :, 2], im1[:, :, 0]

im2 = (imread(".\Example_Figs\poodle.png")[:, :, :3]).astype(np.float32)
im2 = im2 - np.mean(im2)
im2[:, :, 0], im2[:, :, 2] = im2[:, :, 2], im2[:, :, 0]

im3 = (imread(".\Example_Figs\dog.png")[:, :, :3]).astype(np.float32)
im3 = im3 - np.mean(im3)
im3[:, :, 0], im3[:, :, 2] = im3[:, :, 2], im3[:, :, 0]

im4 = (imread(".\Example_Figs\dog2.png")[:, :, :3]).astype(np.float32)
im4 = im4 - np.mean(im4)
im4[:, :, 0], im4[:, :, 2] = im4[:, :, 2], im4[:, :, 0]

im5 = (imread(".\Example_Figs\quail.jpg")[:, :, :3]).astype(np.float32)
im5 = im5 - np.mean(im5)
im5[:, :, 0], im5[:, :, 2] = im5[:, :, 2], im5[:, :, 0]


t = time.time()
output = sess.run(probs, feed_dict={x: [im1, im2, im3, im4, im5]})

# Print Output
for input_im_ind in range(output.shape[0]):
    inds = np.argsort(output)[input_im_ind, :]
    print("Image", input_im_ind)
    for i in range(5):
        print("%s: %.3f" % (class_names[inds[-1 - i]], output[input_im_ind, inds[-1 - i]]))
    print()

print("Time: %.3f seconds" % (time.time() - t))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify what you mean by "entire dataset". Do you mean the train and test set concatenated together? If so, then that set is in your **data** and **labels** variables before splitting. You can pass those into **sess.run** doing something like this to get the total loss. You might have to tweak it a little so the indexes match.

```
feed = {data_pl: data, target_pl: labels,...}
loss = sess.run(tf_loss, feed_dict=feed)
```

If you just want the train/test set errors independently, you are already doing that so just pick up the values from the last epoch run. These are the lines where that is already being done.

```
test_loss,predictions,acc_np = sess.run([tf_loss,preds,tf_acc],feed_dict=feed)
train_loss = sess.run(tf_loss, feed_dict=feed)
```